# Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535 when attempting SSH in Corporate Proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy

I've been trying to set up a SSH jump server in order to connect to my servers when I'm at work, which is employing a really annoying (and slow) corporate proxy and blocking everything going to the outside besides port 443 and 80.

I've set up a test server, which I will use as a jump server if this works, to accept SSH connection on port 443.

This is how I'm trying to connect

```
ssh -vvv ubuntu@jump-ssh-server -p 443 -o ProxyCommand="ncat --proxy proxy_server:3128 --proxy-auth proxy_user:proxy_password -C %h %p"
```

If I try to run only the `ProxyCommand` in the terminal it works. However, when I try to run it with the ssh connection I get an error

```
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.5
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname jump_server is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ncat --proxy proxy_server:3128 --proxy-auth user:password -C jump_server 443
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to jump_server:443 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: put_host_port: [jump_server]:443
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: no algorithms matched; accept original
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 3
debug1: Received SSH2_MSG_UNIMPLEMENTED for 0
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

Is this caused by my corporate firewall trying to block the connection? Is there any way around it?

Comment: Pretty sure that @adnan 's answer below is correct.  Notice the back-and-forth sequence of `debug3: send packet` and `debug3: send packet`? ...this shows there *is some* communication happening between your `ssh` client and the `sshd` on jump-ssh-server!  But `UNIMPLEMENTED` -> they cannot agree on a common algorithm to use.  (1) on CLIENT: `ssh -Q key` (openssh 6.3+) to see what algos your client can speak; (2) on jump-ssh-server: check `sshd_config` file for `Ciphers` or `man -S 5 sshd_config` for what the defaults are.  Newer ssh versions refuse to speak old algos/ciphers.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with ssh, my problem was Kex Algorithm mismatch. I added the same Kex algorithm on both client and destination servers and fixed it.

In `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` I added:

```bash
Host *
    KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
```

you can see my investigation in detail here:

https://blog.adnanebrahimi.com/gitlab-cicd-strange-ssh-issue-on-ssh2msgkexecdhreply

Comment: For future searchers:  Once proxies / ProxyCommand /  jump-hosts comes into play lots of "normal" failures can turn into the super-unhelpful `Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535`  :-(  F/ex: see also https://serverfault.com/a/1070452/45143

Answer (score 0):

Administrating Linux machines from the Windows WSL2 terminal (Ubuntu 22.04), the problem disappears when I define `ssh-agent` variables.

Try to run the following commands before running the command :

```bash
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add -D
```

Answer (score 0):

Some ssh algorithms, like ssh-rsa, are no longer considered safe and are omitted by default from Ubuntu 22.04, so you must manually add them. In my case, it's the `ssh-rsa` algorithm.

@Adnan answer is fine if you are `sudo` and want to override the defaults for every user. But if you are not sudo, or want to make the change for your user then add make the change in your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file as shown below

```bash
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**